# New Android smartphone USB tethering problem in Ubuntu 20.04 and other versions/distributions

Tags: 20.04, usb, android, fedora, tethering

I am having problems with the USB tethering function on Samsung Galaxy A12. I tested it on Windows 10 and is working fine, but when I tested it on Ubuntu 22.04, 20.04, 18.04, 16.04 and the latest Fedora version, I noticed that it is not working. I have activated "Developer options", "USB Debugging" and disabled "Tethering Hardware Acceleration", but none helped. I tried all the possible combinations of these developer options. I upgraded the A12's firmware to the latest version, but it didn't help. The DHCP server on A12 is not responding when connected to a Linux system.
The tethering option is working fine on older smartphones connected to a Linux system. I tried changing the MAC address and/or disabling Network Manager to manually manage the interface, but it didn't help. I can't tell if the problem is with the phone or the system. What can be done?

Comment: Are you trying to setup the Galaxy as "network provider" or are you talking about mtp/file transfer? (I assume the former) Tethering is a little ambiguous term.

Comment: I am trying to setup the Galaxy as "network provider".
Consider my Linux PC as not being connected to a wired/wireless network. I need to access the Internet from my Linux PC via the smartphone only by using USB tethering.

Comment: Ok, not sure if [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868936/use-usb-tether-from-brand-new-galaxy-s7) helps you. Some Samsung devices seem to be difficult.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the Android developer options completely. I was having the same problem with USB tethering not working and this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: The OP said he only turned on the developer options AFTER it did not work so this is not an answer.